# PHP variables through links

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

I got those php files called: clients,type and info.

Imagine a website like facebook.

You have your: www.site.web/profile?=232 , and you click an album, now you have www.site.web/profile?=232&album=10, so you click a photo you have www.site.web/profile.php?=232&album=10&photo=1.

I want to understand you they make this..keeping that "profile.php"

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking about how to pass parameters through URLs?

Comment: Hi, sorry, ive just seen now how to accept the awsers :s

Comment: Im asking how to keep/pass "old vars" on link and load new stuff on my main page depending of those vars.

Comment: IF client=1 a page appear, If client=1&type=1 a difrente stuff apear but in the same main page. I cant explain better. English is not my native language as you already realise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to use hidden inputs to keep your variables being passed from page to page.

Use something like this in a form:

```
<form method='get'>
    <input type='hidden' name='client' value='1'>
    // Your other inputs
</form>
```

This way when you get one input, you can keep passing it from page to page using some simple PHP code to pick it up from the URL and display it again as needed.

Edit: (Further explanation)

When you are passing data through the URL from one page to another you can use some simple PHP code to see if something exists to pass it further along - like this:

```
<?php //page1.php

if(isset($_GET['user']))
{
    $user=htmlspecialchars($_GET['user']);
}

if(isset($_GET['photo']))
{
    $photo=htmlspecialchars($_GET['photo']);
}

// Check for anything else you want as needed.

?>
```

Then, when actually making your links you can do something like:

```
<?php

    $baseAddress="<a href='thePageIwant.php?thisVar=3";
    if(isset($user))
    {
        $baseAddress.="&user=".$user;
    }

    if(isset($photo))
    {
        $baseAddress.="&photo=".$photo;
    }
    // Add any other variables as needed

    $baseAddress.="'>
?>
```

In the HTML output section of your page, you can then use this:

```
<p>Some text and then a link <?php echo $baseAddress;?>Your Link Text</a></p>
```

And your link will appear with all the other variables being passed via the URL. In this case, if user was passed to the page with ID 4, and photo was passed to the page with ID 6, the HTML output would be:

```
<p>Some text and then a link <a href='thePageIwant.php?thisVar=3&user=4&photo=6'>Your Link Text</a></p>
```

If only the user was passed in the URL, and there was no `photo=6` the output would be like this:

```
<p>Some text and then a link <a href='thePageIwant.php?thisVar=3&user=4'>Your Link Text</a></p>
```

Comment: No No. Imagine a website like facebook. You have your www.site.web/profile?=232 , and you click an album, now you have www.site.web/profile?=232&album=10, so you click a photo you have www.site.web/profile.php?=232&album=10&photo=1. I want to understand you they make this..keeping that "profile.php"

Comment: Added extra PHP solution for you.

Comment: Come on, keep em coming, a *Reversal* here would be extra sweet :)